# Humanity as space nomads

Tags: story-identification, books

I was trying to remember a book where humans divided on two clans (primary and secondary). Secondary are space nomads that merge with their starships, and primary are a very advanced with the capability of creating matter and using artificial stars as fortress. Also the secondary clans wipe out an entire spacefaring civilization as retaliation for destroying a primitive human colony.

Galactic community discuss if they must attack humans.

Comment: Somewhat similar to some of the themes in Dan Simmons' *Hyperion* / *Endimion* tetrology, but only somewhat, so I am leaving that as a comment.

Comment: Oh, i love Hyperion. But it's not what i'm looking for, i think is a much less known book.

Comment: Was this an older book can you recall?                                                    I have a vague memory of a Golden Age novel with a somewhat similar premise

Comment: I have no idea, but the ideas of matter generation to build stars, sounds more recent to me.